# How to make child widget scrollable in GTK C++?

Tags: c++, gtk3

i'm new to GTK in C++ and I'm wondering how to make child widget scrollable, just like in this picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwO9E.png) from gtk3-widget-factory (widget in bottom or widget in top). I'm not asking for whole window scrollable, but just half of it or something alike in this picture.

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements: it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself.  Please [edit] your question to show [your attempt far](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and you'll be much more likely to receive answers that help you progress.  Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`GtkScrolledWindow` is what you are looking for.

By the way, you can use Gtk inspector (`ctrl+shift+i`) which can show widget hierarchy.